# create and set an object

Tags: java, android, class, object

I want to place my dataSet values into an object.
I am a newbie. I want to create an object and place these values in it like below.
How can I do this???

obj:

```
{
   dataType: _____,     //dataSet.getDataType().getName()
   Value: ______,      //dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
   startTime: ____,    //dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
   endTime: _____     //dp.getValue(field).toString()
}
```

```
private static void dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Name: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
                Log.v(TAG, "Fields: " + dataSet.getDataSource().getDataType().getFields());

                Log.v(TAG, "Data Point Values :" + dataSet.getDataPoints());
                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Data Point:");
                    Log.v(TAG, "Type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                    Log.v(TAG, "Start: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    Log.v(TAG, "End: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Field: " + field.getName() + ", Value : " + dp.getValue(field).toString());
                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: are you trying to convert it into json object or do you have other class ?

Comment: trying to convert to json object

Answer (score 0):

You can directly using `JSONObject` and add `value` with associated `key` to that

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("dataType", dataSet.getDataType().getName());
 jsonObject.put("Value", dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
 jsonObject.put("startTime", dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
 jsonObject.put("endTime", dp.getValue(field).toString());
```

using `jsonObject.toString()` you can get the `String` format of `Json`.

Comment: This will create a local jsonObject right. Can i call this JSONobject in another class??

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use   the Jackson API ObjectMapper class to convert Java Object to jsonString.

first add these dependancies:

```
implementation  'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.3'
implementation  'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.3'
implementation  'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3'
```

to your build.gradle (app level) file.
after that:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
  String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataSet);
  System.out.println("ResultingJSONstring = " + json);

} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if you need To convert it to Json Object then:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Gson

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

like this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(dp));
```